# Problema com consulta de data no postgresql

Tags: postgresql

boa tarde, estou tentando fazer uma consulta num banco de dados postgresql e aparece um erro bem estranho.

A consulta é select observation_date from jplus.ReducedIndividualFrame where observation_date>00000000000000

Onde observation_date é uma data, que segundo quem implementou é um inteiro long do formato yyyymmddhhmmss.

Quando faço isso aparece o seguinte erro:

java.io.IOException: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone > integer
LINE 1: ...lus.ReducedIndividualFrame WHERE observation_date > 00000000...
^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

```
at uk.ac.starlink.vo.TapQuery.readResultVOTable(TapQuery.java:671)
at uk.ac.starlink.vo.TapQuery.executeSync(TapQuery.java:246)
at uk.ac.starlink.vo.TapTableLoadDialog$6.loadTables(TapTableLoadDialog.java:539)
at uk.ac.starlink.table.gui.TableLoadWorker.run(TableLoadWorker.java:118)
```

Alguém sabe como fazer essa consulta?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Tenho uma tabela que possui uma coluna chamada observation_date que é uma data, mas segundo quem implementou é do tipo long e tem o formato de um inteiro do tipo YYYYMMDDHHMMSS. Eu preciso fazer uma consulta que pega as linhas da tabela cuja data são maiores que uma data desse formato. Então usando o TOPCAT eu fiz a consulta:

select observation_date from jplus.ReducedIndividualFrame where observation_date > 20151130000000

Que resultou no erro:

java.io.IOException: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone > bigint
LINE 1: ...lus.ReducedIndividualFrame WHERE observation_date > 20151130...
^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Alguém pode me ajudar a descobrir como resolver o erro?

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).